# "The requested snapshot version is too old." error in Firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

While using Swift client for firebase, starting Feb 09, I started to see the error message **"The requested snapshot version is too old."** in the callback of addSnapshotListener.

What does that error mean?

How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you only have the client on swift? is it constant or intermittent?

Comment: I am only using Swift for now. Well, actually I use Typescript on server side but I am not adding snapshot listeners there. It is intermittent.

Comment: Can you include a code snippet where that error is being generated from? And also update the question as to how/where you are seeing that error. e.g does it print to console or crash or what?

Comment: Were you able to pinpoint the issue? I'm facing this error but in my cloud function

Comment: I am not 100% sure but I think that this might happen when a user is disconnected for a long time so the client snapshot version is really old. That means the client can't update to the latest version just by getting the changes so it fails. The workaround we had was to assume Firestore will throw transient errors so we added automatic retries to the snapshot listeners using exponential backoff. This workaround has worked pretty well for us so far. Cloud functions should be stateless functions so I think you shouldn't add snapshot listeners there, use Cloud Firestore function triggers instead.

Comment: This also seems to happen when you load a big collection of documents in one query. We have a data-dump routine that downloads all documents of a collection at once. When the dataset on Firestore grew larger, we suddenly got this error. Maybe there is some sort of internal timeout that causes it. Resolved the problem by paginating the data.

Comment: @cheesus is it okay if u send me gists on how you paginate data? im stuck in this problem too, i used node firebase sdk

Comment: @elpmid see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors)